# How can I share my API key in a user script (tamper monkey) without revealing it?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

My Tamper Monkey user script uses an API key as part of its main feature. I want to share the script without exposing the key (currently hard-coded). Is there any way around this?

The only solution I can think of so far is to have each user create their own API key and paste it into the script, which is not ideal especially for non-developer users.

Perhaps there's a way to host my API key somewhere, make a call to fetch the config, then load the key into the script?

Comment: Any "fetch" request would be visible by the developer in the networking console.  Or if they really want to get it, they can alter your script to log it, or they can add debugger statements.

Comment: The only way to keep the API key safe would be to bounce the request off your *own* server.

Comment: Most open source project I come across that use API keys usually have the user generate their own.

Comment: @StrayAnt awesome--good to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Perhaps there's a way to host my API key somewhere, make a call to fetch the config, then load the key into the script?

Even if you do this, the api key will be accessible at some point.
You can either go with your solution and generate api keys for each user, or have a server (or even a simple cloud function) between the script and the external service.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into using an aws lambda function.
Is it unusual for user scripts to use API keys? I found it odd that I couldn't find any information on this (maybe didn't do adequate searching).

Comment: @marshacker I wouldn't say uncommon - take gmaps or mapbox, for example. Most services allow you to add custom permissions and restrict its usage to a list of domains, among other settings.